# use clean urls for a user page using query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been fighting this for a few hours trying to get it to do what I want.

I have a .htaccess file in my root directory for clean urls that reads as such:

```
#turn on url rewriting
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And then  have a directory `/hnid` with a user.php file in it that accepts a get request with an id. I have a .htaccess file in the `/hnid` folder too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)/?$ user?id=$1 [L]
```

My problems lies in the result. I want to be able to access `/hnid/user/1a` to get to the 27th user (yes, I have handling in the file to convert the id).

user/1a gives a 404, user?id=1a gives a 404, user.php?id=1a works fine, and user.php/11 returns with this message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/hnid/user.php on line 3
```

I am a loss on what to do, but I hope that you wonderful people can enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you update php file, the message `Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/hnid/user.php on line 3` come from PHP warning, not apache.

Comment: Did you try: `RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]`. Look like you miss `.php` in this rule

Comment: maybe I should stop programming...  That is what I tried first and it didn't work for some reason and now it is. Twice today has technology done this to me. Tnanks @Kyle

Comment: @Bartha no problem :) just make my comment an upvote. There may be some caching with apache, you should take a look at that too